# How CodePush bundle download works for the final user?

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I'm trying to understand how the code-push bundle size is calculated to understand the impact of the network requests for the final user

I'm debugging the update_check endpoint that is triggered by codePush.sync and I realize that in some updates the package_size is bigger than the main bundle.

In my case, our bundle have 8.5mb and in some cases the package size on code-push is 9.3mb

But I have some scnarios that the package size is just 2.5mb and there is not so much difference between a bundle and another in terms of assets size

Some has any idea on why this happens?

Thanks in advance